# What factors other than atomic weight affect density of an element?

Tags: density

Iron, for example, has an atomic weight of 55.845

[image]

Whereas hydrogen's atomic weight is 1.008, **1.8%** of Irons.

[image]

And the density of Hydrogen (at STP) is 0.0899 g/L, **1.14%** of of Iron's density of 7.874 g/cc, not an exact ratio relationship, but similar.

What other factors affect density of an element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other factor is the distance between atoms and/or molecules. These distances are huge in a gas like $\ce{H2}$, and very small in solids like metallic iron. And the density of $\ce{H2}$ is not $1.14$% of iron's density, as you state. It is still $1000$ times smaller !

Comment: I forgot to covert between L and cc

Comment: @J. Todd. It is exactly what I told you. This does not change my explanation.

Comment: right, I understand. Is there a formula where you can input the molecular structure / atomic data and get the density?

Comment: No ! Because nobody can guess that the Iron atoms are piled up on a cubic base up to a certain temperature, then it changed to a hexagonal structure at a higher temperature, to go back again to a cubic arrangement at a still higher temperature.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your time even though my question wasnt very well thought out